# Books on co-Heyting algebras (with a view to their logics).

Tags: logic, reference-request, book-recommendation, nonclassical-logic, heyting-algebra

I would like to know more about co-Heyting algebras, particularly from the perspective of their logics (like paraconsistent logics).

What books are available out there on the topic?

It might be that it's too specialised a topic. I get that.

I have looked at the references on the [ncatlab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/co-Heyting+algebra#references). Wikipedia doesn't have much on them.

I guess there's some functor I can exploit then just study Heyting algebras, but that approach doesn't take their logics into consideration all that much.  It'd be great if that work was done for me somewhere.

Comment: At this point, I'm pretty sure I've worked through all books available in English which have Heyting algebras as a primary focus. I really wish this was an anecdote about my superhuman tenacity, but as you might suspect, it's one about the sparseness of the literature. Given that intuitionistic logic is not nearly as niche as its duals, I suspect the text you're looking for is yet to be written.